# Marker change position after opening popup on onTap event

Tags: android, maps

I'm doing an Android app as a school project.
It's basically a weather app that let the user send the local weather information and share it with other people.

The basic implementation require the use Google Maps to show some marker and a popup when the marker is clicked.

Now here's the problem, the markers are show correctly but when I tap on one of them to show the popup, the marker will move from the original position and with it all the markers that use the same resource...

Here two screenshot representing what happen:

[Initial situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxKo2.png) -
[After tap and closing popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svZX7.png)
(The screenshot are a little too big to embed them)

As you may notice from image 2, three markers moved south-est...
I know the issue is caused by the popup that show up but I really can't figure out what is causing the change.

The code is really simple, I wrote it while looking for information, so it's probably similar to other example.

The extension of the ItemizedOverlay class

```
public class ItemizedWeather extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    private MapView mapView;

    private Drawable defaultMarker;

    private MarkerPopup popup;

    public ItemizedWeather(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.defaultMarker = defaultMarker;
        this.mapView = mapView;

        // popup setup
        this.popup = new MarkerPopup(mapView);
        // parameter
        MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
            MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // width
            MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // height
            null,
            MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER
        );
        params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;

        // visibility
        popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // add to view
        mapView.addView(popup, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        // get the clicked element
        OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);

        // set new item
        popup.setData(item);

        // position
        GeoPoint point = item.getPoint();

        // parameter
        MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(
            MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // width
            MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // height
            point,
            MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER
        );
        params.mode = MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;

        // change parameter
        popup.setLayoutParams(params);

        // visibility
        popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // move to point
        mapView.getController().animateTo(point);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {

        // Tap event
        if(super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView)) return true;

        // de-select
        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && popup != null) popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return false;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay, Drawable marker) {
        overlay.setMarker(boundCenterBottom(marker));
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay, int drawable) {
        addOverlay(overlay, mapView.getResources().getDrawable(drawable));
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        addOverlay(overlay, defaultMarker);
    }

    public void doPopulate() {
        this.populate();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
    }
}
```

The MarkerPopup class

```
public class MarkerPopup extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView title;
    private TextView snippet;
    private ImageView image;

    public MarkerPopup(MapView mapView) {
        super(mapView.getContext());

        setupPopup(mapView);

        this.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
        this.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    private void setupPopup(ViewGroup mapView) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mapView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_popup, this);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tTitle);
        snippet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tSnippet);

        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iPopupImage);
    }

    public void setData(OverlayItem item) {
        this.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        setObjects(item);
    }

    private void setObjects(OverlayItem item) {
        // title
        if (item.getTitle() != null) {
            title.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            title.setText(item.getTitle());
            title.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            title.setText("");
            title.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }
        // snippet
        if (item.getSnippet() != null) {
            snippet.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            snippet.setText(item.getSnippet());
        } else {
            snippet.setText("");
            snippet.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        }
        // marker
        if(item.getMarker(0) != null) {
            image.setImageDrawable(item.getMarker(0));
        }
    }
}
```

If is relevant to solve the problem here the popup layout that is inflated in MarkerPopup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="1.5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/black_200"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="2dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iPopupImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sun"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="6dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tTitle"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/placeholder"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:focusable="false" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tSnippet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/placeholder"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/marker_bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope the question is done the right way as it's my first time posting here, and that there's a solution.

Comment: I resolved the problem, for some reason setting manually the marker as I did in the code above, when a popup appear the marker will be moved. Using the default marker resolve the problem.